# iOS App crashes at startup when using Admob implementing CODENAME ONE banner through ios.googleAdUnitId

Tags: codenameone

Now I am implementing Ads using Google Admob, I followed the CODENAME ONE Developer Guide. In Android, it is working fine since the beginning. iOS App crashes at startup.

Comment: I don't think we support the ios.googleAdUnit option anymore as the admob implementation changed too often. We instead support [this](https://github.com/codenameone/admobfullscreen-codenameone/)